# Scheduled Automated Data Export SharePoint Online

Tags: export, data, schedule

We are currently migrating our SharePoint 2010 site to SharePoint O365.  We have a SharePoint list in our on prem solution that takes part numbers out of our ERP systems database.  The users then can use the populated part list in other SharePoint lists for drop down selection of part numbers.  What is the best practice for this on SharePoint 365?  I am assuming we need to export the part list to Azure and then point SharePoint 365 to that table in Azure???  The process needs to be automated and scheduled because the part list can change over time and want the most updated data accessible to SharePoint 365.  I know my assumptions may be way off.  If anyone could just point me in the right direction, it would be very appreciated.  Thanks in advanced.

Tim

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea sounds right. Schedule a timer based Azure function ( most likely in C# or PowerShell) that will sync the ERP data with the list. The function will run in the context of some service account, so permissions shouldnt be an issue